# Algorithm: How to find closest element, having coordinates and dimension

Tags: algorithm, sorting, bounds

I got an Array with objects, each object contains x,y,width and height. e.g. arr[{10,20,200,300},{20,30,100,200},…] Now I would like to find the closest object in this array to a given object, taking its boundaries into account.
How could I achieve that, having for example an x-precedence to the right(finding the closest object on the x-axis situated right from the given object)?

Comment: You will have to define a [metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29#Examples), and how to account for partial overlap (boundaries crossing) and enclosure. Start with brute force. If the time taken actually bothers you, hale a look at [line sweep](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=lineSweep).

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your object's center is `(x,y)` with width `w`, height `h`.

The objects (rectangles, I suppose) in the array has center `(xi, yi)` and width `wi`, `hi`.

Your object will connect to the others either from right-edge, top-edge or bottom-edge whose coordinates are:

```
R1 - R2: ((x+(w/2)), (y-(h/2))) - ((x+(w/2))), ((y+(h/2)))

T1 - T2: ((x-(w/2)), (y+(h/2))) - ((x+(w/2))), ((y+(h/2)))

B1 - B2: ((x-(w/2)), (y-(h/2))) - ((x+(w/2))), ((y-(h/2)))
```

Objects in array may have shortest distance starting from their left-edge, top-edge or bottom-edges which are similar

```
Li1 - Li2: ((xi-(wi/2)), (yi-(hi/2))) - ((xi-(wi/2))), ((yi+(hi/2)))

Ti1 - Ti2: ((xi-(wi/2)), (yi+(hi/2))) - ((xi+(wi/2))), ((yi+(hi/2)))

Bi1 - Bi2: ((xi-(wi/2)), (yi-(hi/2))) - ((xi+(wi/2))), ((yi-(hi/2)))
```

Then,

```
distance = infinite;
shortest = null;
for all object in array
    find min distance for
        R2 to [Li1,Li2] line
        R1 to [Li1,Li2] line
        R2 to [Bi1,Bi2] line
        R1 to [Bi1,Bi2] line
        R2 to [Ti1,Ti2] line
        R1 to [Ti1,Ti2] line

        T2 to [Li1,Li2] line
        T1 to [Li1,Li2] line
        T2 to [Bi1,Bi2] line
        T1 to [Bi1,Bi2] line
        T2 to [Ti1,Ti2] line
        T1 to [Ti1,Ti2] line

        B2 to [Li1,Li2] line
        B1 to [Li1,Li2] line
        B2 to [Bi1,Bi2] line
        B1 to [Bi1,Bi2] line
        B2 to [Ti1,Ti2] line
        B1 to [Ti1,Ti2] line

    if minDistance < distance
        distance = minDistance
        shortest = i
end for
```

You can skip some of these calculations according to the relative position of the objects in the array to your object. For example, if `Ti1 < B1`, you don't need to calculate `[Bi1,Bi2] line` parts.

I feel that this solution is very straight-forward&dummy and will take rough criticisms from the mathematicians, but I wanted to try to see the receptions.

Comment: Taking your last sentence at face value: does this account for enclosure?

Comment: I guess it does not. I thought it doesn't need to, since OP stated that "finding the closest object on the x-axis situated right from the given object", but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you know of any javascript library/implementation? I think it would be also interesting how this could be implemented by "finding closest by expanding boundaries". Enclosures/Overlaps are not necessary for start, but a nice to have in the future.